# Convention to where to declare module.exports on Javascript files

Tags: javascript, modules

Is there any convention to where we should declare the `module.exports` no Javascript/Node.js module files?

Should it be in the beginning of the file like:

```
module.exports = Foo;

function Foo() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
}

Foo.prototype.getBar = function() {
    return this.bar;
}
```

Or should it be in the end of the file:

```
function Foo() {
    this.bar = 'bar';
}

Foo.prototype.getBar = function() {
    return this.bar;
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

I know that there is no technical difference. The first example is perfectly valid because of [declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting).

So I was wondering if there are some kind of best practices.

Comment: One advantage of leaving it on the end is that you can use function objects (`var Foo = function()...`), and yet another way of declaring it is directly (`module.exports.Foo = function()...`).

Comment: I could just `var Foo = function Foo()...` and it would work as well.

Comment: Advantage of putting it at the top: you can see the API of your module at a glance (without having to scroll down).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certainly lots and lots of options, which are all commonly used. But that's terribly annoying. I like to put it at  the end, because that works under all circumstances. Whenever I find myself doing something fancy with module.exports, there is probably a better way to do it.

Most importantly, as always, be consistent. And be consistent in your team.

EDIT: On the same notion, I like to have all `require` statements at the beginning. My Node.js files always look like this:

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const MyClass = require("./MyClass");


class MyOtherClass extends MyClass {}

module.exports = MyOtherClass;
```

Nothing fancy, just the way you would expect it. One class per file, one file per class. Files named after the class they contain, with consisten upper/lowercasing. Have a look at this node module, for some examples: [yaioc](https://github.com/bschaepper/yaioc) (disclaimer: I'm the author, and this is shameless advertising)